# How to indicate that the shell was spawned by ncdu - NCurses Disk Usage?

Tags: zsh, disk-usage, subshell

I employ ncdu, the NCurses Disk Usage tool, in conjunction with zsh and p10k.

Pressing 'b' triggers the spawning of a shell in the current directory.

How can I present this information on-screen to ensure that I retain my previous mental context when revisiting this tab later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`man ncdu`](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/man#KEYS)’s description of <kbd>b</kbd> mentions that

> Ncdu will set the `NCDU_LEVEL` environment variable or increment it before spawning the shell. This variable allows you to detect when your shell is running from within ncdu, which can be useful to avoid nesting multiple instances of ncdu.

You can use that in `~/.zshrc` to customise the prompt if `NCDU_LEVEL` is set:

```
if [ -n "$NCDU_LEVEL" ]; then
    # Add something to PS1
fi
```

This feature was added in [`ncdu` 1.16](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/changes).

Comment: Interesting. Mine doesn't mention that in the documentation.

Comment: Good point, it was added in version 1.16 so for example Debian 11 doesn’t have it.

Comment: ok, thanks; I installed the latest and it fixed my problem